# Deploy a single GAE app over multiple regions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to deploy a single GAE app (an API that will use datastore and GS) in US and EU. Datastore/GS buckets should be synchronized across EU and US regions.

I found that:

1. You can't have modules in different regions.
2. You can't sync datastore/GS buckets out of the box across two regions.

Is there any simple and elegant solution for doing this without writing my own synch mechanism ?

Is there a hidden reason for ignoring these cross datacenter necessities by AWS and GAE ? AWS came out with an S3 replication solution only in march 2015, GAE doesn't offer any chance to sync data across regions. Am I the only one who need to distribute a single application across the globe at low latency or maybe for consistence ?

Comment: where exactly did you read about those 2 constraints? neither of them sound right.

Comment: @jirungaray I tried to accomplish these tasks on my own and since I didn't found out how I started google about my problems and I found some comments here on stackoverflow. I would be 100% glad to be wrong. Can you help me please ? I would like to deploy modules in different regions and I would also want to have datastore data replicated across US and EU region. How can I accomplish this ? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

App Engine is not multi-regional.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations

Google Cloud Storage does not offer a storage class that spans US & Europe or US & Asia.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations

Cloud Datastore does not offer a mode that spans US & Europe or US & Asia.

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/locations

The only pointer I can offer is Google Cloud Spanner which is a relational database service for regional and ***global*** application data.  To meet all of the requirements you listed you'll have to roll your own, unfortunately.